# Hash function and one near hard example?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, computer-science, hash-function

Example: Suppose $H:${$1,...,n$} $\rightarrow ${$1,..,n$} be a uniform hash function. for input $x$, $z$ is equal to number of trailing zero in the right side of $H(x)$. for $0 \leq c \leq 1$ what is the order of probability $ z \geq c \log_2 n$? $C$ is constant here.

Answer: $O(1/n^c)$

How  this this is can be achieved?

**Update**:

The Logarithm base is $2$ not $10$.

Comment: Suppose $n=1,000$, how many elements in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ end on a zero? On 2 zeros? And on 3 zeros? What if $n=1,000,000$ and you look at $1,2,\ldots,6$ zeros?

Comment: my comment was not related to 11-1 and does not involve a factor 2

Comment: $100$ elements in $\{1,\ldots,1000\}$ end on a zero, $10$ elements end on two zeros, $1$ element ends on three zeros. Here, $\log n = 3$, and indeed $(1/1000)^c$ is proportional to $100, 10, 1$ for $c=1/3$, $c=2/3$ and $c=1$, respectively. It is not continuous in $c$, but take a larger $n$ to make it smoother.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the hash function is uniform, to find $P(z \geq c \log n)$ we can simply count the number of elements in $S = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ that satisfy $z \geq c \log n$.

Take $n=2^p$ for some $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $n/2$ elements in $S$ end on one zero, $n/4$ elements end on two zeros, etc. So, $P(z \geq c \log n) = (n/2)/n = 1/2$ for $c\log n =1$, $1/4$ for $c\log n=2$, $1/8$ for $c\log n=3$, etc.

So $P(Z \geq c \log n) = (1/2)^{c \log n} = (1/2^{\log n})^c = (1/n)^c$.

Comment: what is the intuitive idea to use P(z>= CP) instead of z >= C log n?

Comment: so here what is the base of logarithm?

Comment: I means if base of logarithm be $2$ we should change all of $10$ to $2$ am I right?

Comment: @LoveMathContest I used the argument that exactly $n/10$ elements in $S$ end on one zero, which only holds true if $n$ is a power of 10. The base of the logarithm has to match the representation, so can you can use log2, but only for binary representation. If you use log2 with decimal representation, you get: $P(Z \geq c \log_2 n) = P(Z \geq (c / \log 2) \log n) = (1/n)^{c / \log 2}$ which is not $O(1/n^c)$.

Comment: @LoveMathContest you just replace $\log$ with $\log_2$, $10$ with $2$, $100$ with $4$ and $1000$ with $8$.

Comment: sure, so your answer works in this case too. but you mentioned in your comment not !

Comment: please clean comments.